# Jenkins pipeline start depending on other pipeline status

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following setup:

- Pipeline A: starts at 10am
- Pipeline B: starts at 12am

Now i want to add a dependency between those two pipelines. Pipeline B should only start if pipeline A ends with the status successfull. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is it also possible that Pipeline B starts immediatly after A but waits unti 12am before actually doing anything? Why does it have to wait?

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways I know of:

- You can add a stage to the end of pipeline A that executes pipeline B (see the [build step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/)). Use this method if you want to keep all of the build logic, including the inter-project dependencies, in the Jenkinsfile's.
- Set build triggers inside of Jenkins in your pipeline project configuration. See the "Build after other projects are built" checkbox in the configuration for your pipeline project. Use this if you want to keep the dependency logic outside of your Jenkinsfile's.